# How to evaluate $\int \sqrt{(t+2)^2 -3} dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking to evaluate $\int \sqrt{(t+2)^2 -3} dt$.

I am aware that one step to solve this is to use the substitution of  $u=(t+2)/\sqrt{3}$, although I am unsure as to where this has been derived.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use trig substitution (tan substitution)

Comment: Use @Aryadeva 's answer and then use the well known [integral of tangent](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-4-techniques-of-integration/part-a-trigonometric-powers-trigonometric-substitution-and-completing-the-square/session-71-integrals-involving-secant-cosecant-and-cotangent/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses71b.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwinuPDR6f_rAhV8UBUIHXs3CyIQFjAZegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1UaSXiNo4s0iLXPxnZ5Gb9)

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \sqrt{(t+2)^2 -3} dt=\int \sqrt{u^2 -3} du$$
Use a trig substitution like:
$$u=\sqrt 3 \sec v$$
$$ \implies \sqrt{u^2 -3} =\sqrt 3 \tan v$$

Answer (score 0):

$I=\int \sqrt{3}\sqrt{u^2-1} du$.  Now use substitution $u=\cosh{x}$, to get
$\sqrt{u^2-1}=\sinh{x}$.